# Python: permission denied when extracting tar.gz

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to extract all tar.gz inside a folder but I am getting [Errno 13] Permission denied. I have been through different posts related to the problem but nothing helps. Even extracting a specific member inside tar.gz gives same error. Can someone help what could be wrong?

[I want to create a script for unzip (.tar.gz) file via (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887979/i-want-to-create-a-script-for-unzip-tar-gz-file-via-python)

[Python: Extracting specific files with pattern from tar.gz without extracting the complete file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865099/python-extracting-specific-files-with-pattern-from-tar-gz-without-extracting-th)

[Overwrite existing read-only files when using Python's tarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237475/overwrite-existing-read-only-files-when-using-pythons-tarfile)

```
tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Comment: Well obviously you don't have the permissions to create new files. What are your directory permissions?

Comment: I have read & write permissions on the directory on my Mac

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this as a local user?  Is this running on Unix/Linux?  Does the account running the python script have the appropriate rights to the folder you are attempting to write to?

Comment: This is on Mac OSX. I have running this script on same machine in the past. Now I want to add capability to extract tar.gz in the same script

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you do not have permission to the tmp folder on your system.
Make a temporary directory in your home directory :

**mkdir tmp_local**

Try to change the tmp directory to your local folder using the following command:

**export TMPDIR='/local_home/ah32097/tmp_local'**

after this you can directly pip install the python package in tar.gz format.